# How to get opposite user's 'typing...' information in 1-to-1 chat using PHP, jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

We have developed chat application using PHP and jQuery/AJAX where we can send messages as well as media files. It is working properly. The only issue is that we want to provide facility to display 'typing...' text when other/opposite user is typing a message.

Can we get other user's 'typing' information using our current programming structure? If yes then what can be basic scenario to do this? If no then whether we need to change programming languages and which will be best programming languages to make this possible.

Please provide any reference links if available... Thank You.

Below is the basic chat application concept we are using right now.

PHP page to display 1-to-1 chat.

```
<?php
$int_cnt = 0;
$str_desc = "";
$str_desc = $str_pipe_seperated_chat_description;

if($str_desc != "")
{
    $str_diff_desc = array();
    $str_diff_desc = explode("||", $str_desc);

    foreach($str_diff_desc AS $str_msg)
    { 
        $str_msg_diff = array();
        $str_msg_diff = explode("|", $str_msg);
?>
<div class="row padding-10">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10" align="right">Message From Chat User 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row padding-10">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-sm-10" align="right">Reply From Chat User 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2"></div>    
</div>
<?php 
    }
} ?>
```

Form to send Chat Messages including attachment.

```
<div class="row padding-10" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form id="frm_chat" name="frm_chat" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <textarea id="ta_desc" name="ta_desc" rows="2" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Leave a message" tabindex="2"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="file" id="file_large_image" name="file_large_image[]" multiple />
            </div>
            <div id="progress" class="progress" style="display:none;">
                <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
            </div>
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-warning" tabindex=""><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;<b>Send Message</b></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

.js file to send Chat Messages including attachment.

```
<script>
    // JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frm_chat').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ta_desc",$("textarea#ta_desc").val());
        var files = $("input[id=file_large_image]")[0].files;

        $.each($("input[id=file_large_image]"), function(i, obj) {
            $.each(obj.files,function(j, file){
                $('#progress').css('display', '');
                formData.append('file_large_image['+j+']', file);                                
            })
        }); 

        $.ajax({                
                type: 'POST',
                url: './webchat_p.php',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    var $responseText=JSON.parse(data);

                    if($responseText.status == 'SUC') { /* Success message */ }
                    else if($responseText.status == 'ERR') { /* Error message */ }
                }                
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793502/implementing-web-chat-how-do-i-get-typing-status

Comment: As this is a chat app you should be using websockets. As such, simply send an event when a connected user starts typing, just remember to also debounce the notice when the other user has stopped typing after N seconds.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Is it possible to send media files using websocket?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Is it possible to use websocket in our existing chat application code by making necessary changes? Also any reference link to start chat application development using websocket and php? Thank you...

Comment: If you're not already using websockets then you would need to completely restructure your application in order to use them effectively. Sorry, I don't have any PHP resources as I'm a C# dev. I'm sure there's plenty around if you search.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thank you for your help and will get your guidance if needed when we will start development in websocket and php.